# How to call a function on tilt swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

How do I call a function when the screen of a device is tilted left or right in spriteKit? I have already tried using `CMMotionManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the startDeviceMotionUpdates with handler

```
let manager: CMMotionManager = CMMotionManager()
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error!)
    }
    else if data != nil{
        print(data!.rotationRate.x)
        print(data!.rotationRate.y)
        print(data!.rotationRate.z)
        self.runMethod(motionData: data!)
    }
}
```